# I need to select a specific range of dates, ignoring year, from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, algorithm, date, range

Here's my problem. My system stores dates and times in your usual DATETIME format:

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

This is what I have trouble with:

I need to select all the contacts that have a date field in this format:

```
'XXXX-12-02 23:59:59' and every other date 7 days leading up to it.
```

For example, I would need to get all these rows with these dates in response:

```
1965-12-02
1985-11-28
1990-12-01
```

Is this possible and if it is, any help or tips that you can give me?

Comment: Please explian "and every other date 7 days leading up to it"

Comment: I think he means the range (DATE - 7 days --> DATE)

Comment: Yeah, I mean:
DATE <= X < DATE-7

Answer (score 0):

You can get a specific part of your `DATETIME` variable using the following functions.

- `DAY(your_DATETIME_Variable)` --> gets day as integer
- `MONTH(your_DATETIME_Variable)` --> gets month as integer
- `YEAR(your_DATETIME_Variable)` --> gets year as integer

Comment: That's easy as long as the day of month > 7, but the days the OP is looking for may be in another month or even another year than the "seed-date" and then  things starts to get a bit messy to do in SQL...

Comment: This is what my colleague suggested, but it doesn't work exactly for the reason where months (or years) change.

Answer (score 0):

The easy part: To find any date on the same day and month:

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE 
   month(timefield)=month('2012-12-02 23:59:59') 
   and day(timefield) = day('2012-12-02 23:59:59)
```

A messy way of doing it, but it will (mostly) work is to do a

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE 
   (month(timefield)=month('2012-12-02 23:59:59') 
   and day(timefield) = day('2012-12-02 23:59:59')) or
   (month(timefield)=month(date_sub('2012-12-02 23:59:59' interval 1)) 
   and day(timefield) = day(date_sub('2012-12-02 23:59:59') interval 1)) or
   (month(timefield)=month(date_sub('2012-12-02 23:59:59' interval 2)) 
   and day(timefield) = day(date_sub('2012-12-02 23:59:59') interval 2)) or
```

and so on...

Then the problem comes up: What with leap years... I do not have any good solutions for that... If e.g your seed date is 05-mar-2012, then you will only get back to 28-feb-2012, but I guess you want the data back to 27 feb 2011... One possible solution to that is to make sure that you always normalize the date to a leap year, fetch the days 8 days back and throws away what you do not want in the front end.

Comment: Does not work for some reason. Something wrong with the syntax, I don't think you can write it this way.

Comment: thinking a bit more about it. - that's a wrong approach... sorry.

Comment: I have another idea now, a bit messy, but it may work - with a caveat.